# CALayer colorWithPatternImage UIImageOrientation

Tags: iphone, ios, calayer, uiimageorientation

I have used colorWithPatternImage successfully to create a background color in a CALayer I am using for the background of a presentation. However, the image is presented in the color upside-down. I understand from hours of reading posts and the docs that this is because of the reverse screen coordinates.

So, I tried this code which I discovered after hours of reading posts, but it does not work.

pImage used below is loaded previously from a NSURLConnection.

```
flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:pImage.CGImage scale: 1.0f orientation: UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];

self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:flippedImage].CGColor;

self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);
```

I should say that I am doing this in a background thread. I have also tried the other orientations from the docs and none of them work in my code.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

flip the layer!? set geometryFlipped to YES

Comment: I tried self.geometryFlipped = YES and [self setGeometryFlipped:YES]; both did not work.

Comment: Ok, I have discovered that using self.transform = CATransform3DRotate will flip another layer left, but places the top of the layer outside of the bounds of the parent layer. Would someone be able to provide a link of setting and coordinates for this.

Comment: your questuin got edited and now looks cool to me. the UIImage gets flipped BEFORE making the color. that doesnt work either?

Comment: No, did not work - here is the code  flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:pImage.CGImage scale: 1.0f orientation: UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];
                self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:flippedImage ].CGColor;
                
                self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

Comment: Sorry All for answering my own question, but I found the solution by playing around with CATransform3DRotate and CALayer anchorPoint. I thought this may help someone. Here is the code that fixed the problem self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:pImage ].CGColor;
self.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, M_PI, 0, 0, 1);
self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0,1.0);